# need empty row in output between rows with data Report Builder 3.0 T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reportbuilder

I have reports that pull 50 random records. i would like to insert a blank Row in the output between each row of data.  for example, Rows 1,3,5,7... are populated with data, and even number rows are empty.

Thanks

Comment: Do want only 25 of the 50 records to show or you want all 50 to show with a space between each one?

Comment: i want to see all 100 rows . . . Odd rows (doesnt have to be the ODD rows) with data, Even rows blank.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY with NULL valued table gives equal number of rows as original table.
Now we can generate `ROW_NUMBER` for two SELECTs and sort it by row number to get alternate values.

```
select C.id, C.name, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( ORDER BY C.id) as seq from TableC C
UNION ALL
SELECT T.id, T.name, seq as seq
FROM
(
select T.id, T.name ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER by C.id ) as seq from TableC C 
cross apply ( select NULL as id,NULL as name ) T
) T
ORDER BY seq
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution could be :

```
Select id+Temp id, name+Temp name from TableA A
Cross Apply 
(select '' as 'Temp'
union all 
Select null) X
```

If you have large number of columns, then create the concatenation of column_name + temp dynamically and  use that in dynamic sql

for Demo Click on -->  [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a95dc/1)